# Iterative versus continuous auctions

Tags: auctions

I'm a little confused about the terminology used in economics literature while describing iterative and continuous auctions. Have I understood the difference correctly?

Iterative Auction: The auctioneer repeats the auction and the traders submit bids/asks until a purpose (welfare maximization etc.) is reached.

Continous Auction: The auction does not happen only once and there are different rounds of auction happening continuously.